# Changing default location to applications installed on hardware after changing its assigned letter

Tags: drive-letter

I got new work machine at my job with two hard drives but the assignment of letters is terrible. `C:/` is normal `D:/` is for DVD-RW and `F:/` is for second HDD. I wanted to change it to standard `C: D: E:` but after I did all applications installed on `F:` (such MS Office, Visual Studio etc.) stopped working - they are still looking for the path on `F:` drive from their shortcuts. Is there some way to change paths for all installed applications to correct letter after its change?

Comment: application usually store their path data in the registry. editing this for all aplications is slower then uninstalling all applications and reinstalling them on the correct location.

Comment: Repairing the applications is likely the easiest way to accomplish this, however this is a work computer and is not yours. You should really bring this to your IT department's attention. They may have reasons for using that non-standard drive letter setup, and if not, they'll be able to get the application links repaired for you.

Comment: The IT just messed up. They reinstalled it and changed completely. But it took like 2 days of waste of time.